# What was the first use of the driving closeup shots known from Miami Vice?

Tags: first-appearance, cinematography

One of the trademarks of [*Miami Vice*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086759/) were the nightly cruises through Miami's streets, which were usually accompanied by great music and very characteristic camera shots showing closeups of the car while driving, as seen in this pictures and in [various other examples](http://youtu.be/E1o-NWNmQLM).

[image]
[image]

Especially the left one to me is absolutely characteristic for *Miami Vice*. But
I wonder though, if *Miami Vice* was the first movie/TV-show to employ those specific camera shots. Or more generally asked, **what was the first work to use those kinds of driving closeup shots?**

Comment: As much as I would love to add a `miami-vice` tag, I'm not sure the questions deserves it, being just a general first-appearance question after all.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd give the date on (or at least year in) which Miami Vice began using such shots.

Comment: Also, is your question specifically restricted to shots in which the car is shown and camera is mounted on the car and the occupants of the car are not shown?

Comment: @sampablokuper As soon as the pilot episode (from which the examples in the question are). *"Also, is your question specifically restricted to shots in which the car is shown and camera is mounted on the car and the occupants of the car are not shown?"* - Exactly, as the example shows.

Comment: Thanks. That episode apparently premiered on [September 16, 1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Brother%27s_Keeper_(Miami_Vice)&oldid=588677806).

Answer (score 3):

[*Grand Prix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Prix_(1966_film)) (1966) contains some short shots like this (watch [the trailer](http://www.imdb.com/video/screenplay/vi3970041113/) closely). Likewise [*Città violenta*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igX1TNr-cmY#t=0m58s) (1970), [*The Cars That Ate Paris*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKrZ8eTcdK4#t=2m02s) (1974), [*Death Race 2000*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6LahtrxVhg#t=5m11s) (1975), [*The Gumball Rally*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNFcbgQJsfw) (1976) and [*The Spy Who Loved Me*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUxpXy1Oot4#t=3m30s) (1977).